"Munçudo/Munsudo": Moçudo?
O meu avô costumava me chamar de 'munçudo', mas eu nunca dei a isso nenhuma atenção.
Esses dias, porém, eu me lembrei duma conversa minha com ele e esta palavra me veio à mente.
Pesquisei no Google, mas não consegui encontrar absolutamente nada sequer minimamente semelhante.
Minha hipótese é que seja uma alteração da palavra 'moçudo' (moço + -udo).
Eu não tenho nenhuma formação em linguísticas, então eu não posso confirmá-la sozinho.
Para os mais sábios, eis aqui algumas perguntas: é uma hipótese que faz sentido, e, se sim, como que essa(s) 'mudança(s) fonética(s)'(?) pode(m) ter acontecido?
Somos ambos nordestinos do sul do Ceará.


Não sería más fácil ligar aos amigos/pessoas conhecidos por aí? Acho que formação em  linguística não ajuda aqui. Já encontrei dois glosários cearês e não contêm a palavra.

Talvez -surdo em vez de -udo? O único que encontrei na internet foi num site español, recheado com publicidades, que diz que "monsudo" e "monsúo" significam "calado". https://wikirioja.com/riojanismos/monsudo/
